# How does Class.forName() work?

Tags: java, jdbc

I just learned about `java.sql package`. It uses `Class.forName()` to dynamically load the driver which extends `DriverManager`.
Then we get connection using `DriverManager.getConnection()` method.

So how does the entire thing work?
How does DriverManager class know how to get the connection without using class name of the actual driver.

Also can we use Class.forName() for custom applications... if this is explained with an example I will be very happy.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053125/632951

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`Class.forName` simply loads a class, including running its static initializers, like this:

```
class Foo {
    static {
        System.out.println("Foo initializing");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("Foo");
    }
}
```

All the rest of the procedure you're talking about is JDBC-specific. The driver - which implements `Driver`, it doesn't extend `DriverManager` - simply registers an appropriate instance using `DriverManager.registerDriver`. Then when `DriverManager` needs to find a driver for a particular connection string, it calls `connect` on each registered driver in turn until one succeeds and returns a non-null connection.

Note that this way of registering drivers is reasonably old-fashioned - look at the docs for [`DriverManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) for more modern ways of getting at a data source.

Comment: my query is resolve from 1st line for you answer sir.

Comment: @Jon Nice example, but where is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class for `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` as I tried to `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` still not works

Comment: @UnKnown: It's in the MySQL jar file. But you shouldn't need to import it - you usually let JDBC initialize it directly, and you only refer to the JDBC classes in your code.

Comment: @PhilipRego: I've just downloaded `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` and the `com.mysql.jdc.Driver` class is in there.

Comment: `DriverManager` doesn't call `acceptsURL`, it just calls `connect`, and the first to succeed (not return null or throw an exception) is the connection that is returned.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks, will remove that part.

Comment: I have read your answer. But I do not understands what it really does!. I am still confused.

Comment: @Aman: Without any more detail than that, it's hard to know how to help further.

Answer (score 32):

When we create an instace of a class using new operator, it does two things

1. Load the class in to memory, if it is not loaded -
   which means creating in-memory representation of the class from the .class file so that an instance can be created out of it. This includes initializing static variables (resolving of that class)
2. create an instance of that class and store the reference to the variable.

`Class.forName` does only the first thing.
It loads the class in to memory and return that reference as an instance of Class. If we want to create an instance then, we can call newInstance method of that class. which will invoke the default constructor (no argument constructor).
Note that if the default constructor is not accessible, then newInstance method will throw an `IllegalAccessException`. and if the class is an abstract class or interface or it does not have a default constructor, then it will throw an `InstantiationException`. If any exception araises during resolving of that class, it will throw an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

If the default constructor is not defined, then we have to invoke the defiend constructor using reflection API.

But the main advantage with Class.forName is, it can accept the class name as a String argument. So we can pass the class name dynamically. But if we create an instance of a class using new operator, the class name can't be changed dynamically.

`Class.forName()` inturn will call loadClass method of the caller ClassLoader (ClassLoder of the class from where `Class.forName` is invoked).

By default, the `Class.forName()` resolve that class. which means, initialize all static variables inside that class.
same can be changed using the overloaded method of `Class.forName(String name,boolean initialize,ClassLoader loader)`

The main reason for loading jdbc driver using `Class.forName()` is, the driver can change dynamically.
in the static block all Drivers will create an instance of itself and register that class with DriverManager using `DriverManager.registerDriver()` method. Since the `Class.forName(String className)` by default resolve the class, it will initialize the static initializer.
So when we call `Class.forName("com.sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")`, 
the Driver class will be loaded, instanciated and registers with DriverManager

So if you are using new Operator you have to do the following things.
Code:

```
Driver drv = new com.sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);
```

Comment: That's a great description! Thank you for mentioning the newInstance, I was confused as to if the class is instantiated using a constructor or ONLY instantiating the static members. So basically using forName we instantiate the static members only, then the manager somewhere in the code is using the newInstance and starts using it, correct?

Answer (score 17):

`Class.forName(..)` loads and initializes the target class. This in turn means that the static initializer blocks are invoked (code defined in `static { .. }`.

If you look at, for example, MySQL's driver, in that static block the driver is registering itself: `DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());`

You can omit the `Class.forName(..)` and register the driver yourself if you can "afford" the compile-time dependency on MySQL's driver.

That said, it will rarely be relevant to use `Class.forName(..)` to initialize classes from your application, because compile-time dependency is not an issue there.

Also note that `Class.forName(..)` [is no longer required](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) for JDBC since version 4. By using the [service provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism you can instruct the driver manager what to load by a system property.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `Class.forName()` is frequently mentioned in SQL examples, is because there was no magic to tell the JDBC DriverManager *how* to map the JDBC URL provided to a real driver.

E.g. "mysql" should map to a given MySQL class, "thin" maps to the Oracle class, "as400" maps to the DB2/400 class.

By explicitly loading the class, this allowed the code within the class registering itself with the DriverManager to be run.

These days the magic hooks are present allowing the JVM to autodiscover the drivers (if new enough) so the call is superfluous, but out of habit many still use it.