# Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"); issue

Tags: java, hsqldb

Hei, im trying to connect to h database, via my java program but having problems with my driver issue. I am using ATOM editor not Eclipse or NetBeans!! How can I run my java program via ATOM editor??
I know that i need to  include the HSQL JDBC driver in my class path but how can i do that?
Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class ConnectDatabase {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Connection con = null;

  try {
     //Registering the HSQLDB JDBC driver
     Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
     //Creating the connection with HSQLDB

     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.", "SA", "");
     if (con!= null){
        System.out.println("Connection created successfully");

     }else{
        System.out.println("Problem with creating connection");
     }

  }  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: `Class.forName` [hasn't been required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18058928/15880) for DB Drivers for a *very* long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add hsqldb jar to classpath, in this case you can copy it to folder where your Java class is located, then you need to compile it with `-cp` flag for example `javac -cp ./hsqldb.jar ConnectDatabase.java` and run the program with 
`java -cp ".:./hsqldb.jar" ConnectDatabase` in case when you have Linux or `java -cp ".;./hsqldb.jar" ConnectDatabase` on Windows

Comment: Thank You so much. You made my day :) I had my jar file located to the folder but was compiling not right and couldn't find an answer on internett.

Comment: @ViktorijaBlaziene Awesome :) if your problem is resolved I'd suggest you mark it as answered.