# Why do I need to use Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") and why my code works without it?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

1. Why I need to use `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` and what is it stands for?
2. Why my code work without it despite everywhere says that it wouldn't work without it? (I used it in empty project so `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` has not been executed there)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
        final String USER = "postgres";
        final String PASSWORD = "123";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM students;";
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        )
        {
            System.out.println("Connected successfully");
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                int age = resultSet.getInt("age");
                System.out.printf("name: %s, age: %d\n", name, age);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058714/java-class-forname-jdbc-connection-loading-driver/

Comment: The answer is "you don't, and be very careful about whatever tutorial you are using".

Comment: It's probably that the tutorial is using an old version of Java and JDBC where the explicit class loading was required back then.