# Could not find class while executing program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the sample java code

```
class Candy {
    static {
        print("Loading candy");
    }
}

class Gum {
    static { 
        print("Loading Gum"); 
    }
}

class Cookie {
    static { 
        print("Loading Cookie"); 
    }
}


public class SweetShop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("inside main");
        new Candy();
        print("after creating candy");
        try{
            Class.forName("Gum");   
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            print("could not find gum class");
        }
        print("After Class.forName(\"Gum\")");
        new Cookie();
        print("After creating Cookie");
    }
}
```

When execute always i am getting out put as

> inside main
>
> Loading candy
>
> after creating candy
>
> could not find gum class
>
> After Class.forName("Gum")
>
> Loading Cookie
> Please provide some help.
> After creating Cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you have a package:

```
   Class.forName("package_name.Gum");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you class is package private as you have not specified any access modifier to it.

Try:

```
public class Gum {
   static { print("Loading Gum"); }
}
```

Comment: If that is the solution, would the answer to this question also not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202252/how-does-class-forname-work

Comment: @Trobbins if they are in the same package then it will work hence I have asked for the package structure to get more clarity.

Comment: Right, but his code snippet implies the code is within the same file, which is why I asked. Guess I'm just making an Ass out of U and Me :)