# Why do I need [Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");]?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

In that site, Class.forName is no longer needed.
(that file based Java11, JavaEE8 with gradle)

but In my case.

If I didn't use this.

> Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")

HTTP:500 error occurred and that error message is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydb

Otherwise when I use that code, It work well.

> Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")

Why do they need [Class.forName]?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
    Connection conn = null;

    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "1234"); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
%>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202252/how-does-class-forname-work

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC 4 standard introduced automatic registration of JDBC drivers. Earlier drivers had to manually be registered by forcing the classloader to load them, e.g., by calling `Class.forName`.

It seems you're using an older version of the driver  that still requires the `Class.forName` call.

Comment: In gradle.build that implements 
'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.7'

MariaDB Connector/J 3.0's JDBC version is 4.2.

I don't understand what happened :<